# Cannot find type definition file for ‘zen-observable'

Tags: angular, npm, ionic3

I'm working with Ionic 3, I just choose aws default template and I get an error:

```
> ionic start app0 aws // aws is a default starting app in Ionic3 
> cd app0
> ionic serve
```

When I serve :

## Error:

```
[app-scripts] [16:44:12]  typescript: node_modules/aws-amplify/lib/PubSub/Providers/MqttOverWSProvider.d.ts, line: 2 
[app-scripts]             Cannot find type definition file for 'zen-observable'. 
[app-scripts]        L1:  import { Client } from 'paho-mqtt';
[app-scripts]        L2:  import * as Observable from 'zen-observable';
[app-scripts]        L3:  import { AbstractPubSubProvider } from './PubSubProvider';
[app-scripts] [16:44:12]  typescript: node_modules/aws-amplify/lib/PubSub/Providers/PubSubProvider.d.ts, line: 1 
[app-scripts]             Cannot find type definition file for 'zen-observable'. 
[app-scripts]        L1:  import * as Observable from 'zen-observable';
[app-scripts]        L2:  import { PubSubProvider, ProvidertOptions } from '../types';
[app-scripts]             Cannot find type definition file for 'zen-observable'. 
[app-scripts] [16:44:12]  typescript: node_modules/aws-amplify/lib/PubSub/PubSub.d.ts, line: 1 
[app-scripts]        L1:  import '../Common/Polyfills';       
[app-scripts]        L2:  import * as Observable from 'zen-observable';
[app-scripts] [16:44:12]  typescript: node_modules/aws-amplify/lib/PubSub/types/Provider.d.ts, line: 1 
[app-scripts]             Cannot find type definition file for 'zen-observable'. 
[app-scripts]        L1:  import * as Observable from 'zen-observable';
[app-scripts]        L2:  import { ProvidertOptions } from './PubSub';
```

## Ionic Info:

> Ionic:
>
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.3.1
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v8.9.4
>      npm    : 6.4.1
>      OS     : Linux 4.13

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
npm install –save-dev @types/zen-observable
npm install –save-dev @types/paho-mqtt
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install a package named "@types/zen-observable" simply using command below :

```
npm install @types/zen-observable
```